# Environment variables for tests in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, testing, environment-variables

I have a config in services.yaml

```
parameters:
   locale: 'en'
   uri: '%env(resolve:DEV_ENV_URI)%'
```

But when I execute tests, where I have used this parameter like

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient();

    static::bootKernel();

    $this->container = static::$kernel->getContainer();

    $this->guzzle = new Client(
        [
            'base_uri' => $this->container->getParameter('uri'),
            'verify' => false
        ]
    );
}
```

I have got the following error:

> Environment variable not found: "DEV_ENV_URI".

Here is my `.env`:

```
APP_ENV=test
DEV_ENV_URI=http://0.0.0.0:8000/
```

In dev environment during requests everything is great, but when I run tests from the terminal, the environment is not working.

Maybe you can suggest any other idea, how to solve the problem with establishing base URI for testing reason?

Thanks a lot for any idea!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the proper way to fix this is to use the configuration file of PHPUnit:

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" />
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="test" />
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="1" />
        <env name="APP_SECRET" value="s$cretf0rt3st" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used old-fashioned way, create parameters.yml and add it into gitignore.